# how to print out stack trace of function call that has already been returned?

Tags: python

For example:

```
with magically_trace_stack() as trace:
    func(1, 2)
print(trace.format_tb())
```

`func` can call dozens of other functions and I want to know which ones.

(ps: **don't** suggest me a debugger)

#### extended example

```
def b():
    print('b')

def a():
    print('a')
    b()

def func():
    print('func')
    a()

with magically_trace_stack() as trace:
    func()
trace.print_stack()
```

and printed stack should look like:

```
called func
called a
called b
exit b
exit a
exit func
```

Functions `a` and `b` are hidden and I can only access `func`.

Comment: Do you want an stack trace, i.e. a rolled-out stack of calls up to one particular point in the execution, or a trace of executed functions, as in "how many times have each function been called after the `trace` block is finished?

Comment: `trace.format_exc()` works quite nicely for me

Comment: @jdehesa rolled-out stack of calls

Comment: @Aiven Up to which point exactly? I assume it's not up to the point of an error, since exceptions already do that. When you have exited the context manager there is no stack of calls anymore, because `func` and all its nested calls have returned. What point in the execution of the function would you like to see snapshotted?

Comment: "exited the context manager there is no stack of calls anymore". This is why I asked this question. I want to know how to tell python to store "somewhere" function calls which was popped out from the stack and then use this "somewhere" (eg print it out or do something else)

Comment: Please give an example code definition of `func` and the traceback output you are expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a context manager class that enables the interpreter's trace function with [`sys.settrace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) with a method that appends the trace events and frames to a list:

```
import sys

class magically_trace_stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.events = []

    def __enter__(self):
        sys.settrace(self.trace)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        sys.settrace(None)

    def trace(self, frame, event, arg):
        # we don't want to record the call to the exit of the context manager
        if frame.f_code is not self.__exit__.__func__.__code__:
            self.events.append((frame, event, arg))
        return self.trace

    def print_stack(self):
        for frame, event, arg in self.events:
            if event == 'call':
                print(f'called {frame.f_code.co_name}')
            elif event == 'return':
                print(f'exit {frame.f_code.co_name} with {arg}')
```

so that:

```
def b():
    print('b')
    return 1

def a():
    print('a')
    b()
    return 2

def func():
    print('func')
    a()

with magically_trace_stack() as trace:
    func()
trace.print_stack()
```

outputs:

```
func
a
b
called func
called a
called b
exit b with 1
exit a with 2
exit func with None
```

Comment: This does not add the right line numbers when i use the following code which uses pennylane module:
import pennylane as  qml
dev = qml.device('default.qubit', wires=2)

@qml.qnode(dev)
def awa():
    qml.PauliY(0)
    return qml.expval(qml.PauliZ(0))

when i look for the line number of qml.PauliY(0) it gives me a number that is not the correct line number. What can i do in this case?